# get value from edit text and do some calculations

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext, textview

i have a fragment with 3 edit texts and 1 text view. i want to get inputs from those edit texts. but it force closes. what is the problem?
my code:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bmi_fragment,
            container, false);
    EditText age = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_age);
    EditText weight = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_weight);
    EditText height = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_height);
    int age_value = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
    int weight_value = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
    int height_value = Integer.parseInt(height.getText().toString());
    int calc = (weight_value / ((height_value / 100) * (height_value / 100)));
    TextView dd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_bmi_textView);
    dd.setText(calc);
```

Comment: Problem is in `dd.setText(calc);` line use `dd.setText(String.valueOf(calc));` to show `int` in TextView and also get values from EditText on any event like on click of button otherwise `Integer.parseInt` throw `NumberFormatException ` if value if empty return by getText() method of EditText's

Comment: any data did you set int editext?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK it again force closes

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: @Cgx editTexts are empty at the start of app

Comment: @madhankumar no error message. just force close

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK yes you are right. there is no button. how we can do it without adding buttons? i mean i have seen some apps doing calculations as you change the edit text

Comment: @zorer: Then use `TextWatcher`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a control for empty EditText

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bmi_fragment,
        container, false);
EditText age = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_age);
EditText weight = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_weight);
EditText height = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_height);
try {
        int age_value = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
        int weight_value = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
        int height_value = Integer.parseInt(height.getText().toString());
        int calc = (weight_value / ((height_value / 100) * (height_value / 100)));
        TextView dd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        dd.setText(calc+"");
} catch (Exception e){
    //Textfield empty
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use setText() like that

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bmi_fragment,
            container, false);
    EditText age = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_age);
    EditText weight = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_weight);
    EditText height = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_height);
    int age_value = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
    int weight_value = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
    int height_value = Integer.parseInt(height.getText().toString());
    int calc = (weight_value / ((height_value / 100) * (height_value / 100)));
    TextView dd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_bmi_textView);
    dd.setText(""+calc);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.SetText()`. but you are passing `int` type. that's a problem. so you need to convert your `int to String`

Try like,

```
 dd.setText("Value : " + calc); // concat with String 
 dd.setText("" + calc); // concat with empty string
```

or you may use `Integer.toString(int)`

```
 dd.setText(Integer.toString(calc));
```

or use `String.valueOf(int)`

```
dd.setText(String.valueOf(calc));
```

this may helps you

**Without Button** : Need to add `TextChangedListener`

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bmi_fragment,
        container, false);
EditText age = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_age);
EditText weight = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_weight);
EditText height = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_height);
int age_value = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
int weight_value = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());

TextView dd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_bmi_textView);


 editText_height.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
          {
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int count, int after){} 

               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) 
               {

                   int height_value = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());              
                   int calc = (weight_value / ((height_value / 100) * (height_value / 100)));
                   dd.setText(calc);
               }

          });
```

Comment: it still force closes but when i add a button to do the calculation when button clicked, it works. how can i start the calculations without adding button and just when user changes edittexts value?

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bmi_fragment,
        container, false);
EditText age = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_age);
EditText weight = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_weight);
EditText height = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText_height);
int age_value = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
int weight_value = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
int height_value = Integer.parseInt(height.getText().toString());
int calc = (weight_value / ((height_value / 100) * (height_value / 100)));
TextView dd = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.result_bmi_textView);
dd.setText(String.valueOf(calc));
```